# jquery autocomplete only the first textfield

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a problem with the autocomplete - it works only for the first text field.

```
$(function(){
    var all_analysts = [<TMPL_VAR ALL_ANALYSTS>];
    $('.aucomplete').autocomplete({
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
        // callback function:
        //onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },////////////add a check if the name exists
        // local autosugest options:
        lookup: all_analysts //local lookup values
    });

});
```

* contains the months (JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH...).

Two text fields:

```
<input type="text" name="q1" class="aucomplete" value="hello" />
<input type="text" name="q2" class="aucomplete" value="hello" />
```

The fiest text field (q1) works fine but the secod (q2) doesn't suggest/complete.
please note that when loading/refreshing the page it adds autocomplete="off" to the first text field:

```
<input type="text" name="q1" class="aucomplete" value="hello" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="text" name="q2" class="aucomplete" value="hello" />
```

I'm using the devbridge module.

Do you know what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I solve it by using 'each'...

Comment: This implies that the plugin is not written according to the jquery standards. Why aren't you using jQueryUI autocomplete? The devbridge plugin is from the stone age!

Comment: It doesn't worked for me in the standard package (1.8.16).

Comment: I already had the devbridge installed so I continued with it...

Comment: Do you suggest to start it from scrach with the  jQueryUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my jQueryUI variant, check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/BWCpj/

`lookup` is not an option in the jQuery UI autocomplete; it should be `source`. For the rest of the options you can check the documentation at
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/